# Assert an error is thrown using the new to execute a constructor function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

Using Chai with Mocha, what syntax would I use to assert that an error is thrown when using the new keyword to execute a constructor function?  I get an error when I use the following:

`assert.throw(new SomeFunction, Error);`

This returns:

`AssertionError: expected { Object () } to be a function`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass a function to `assert.throw`:

```
assert.throw(function () {
    new SomeFunction()
}, Error);
```

The reason what you had did not work is that the `new SomeFunction` is interpreted as `new SomeFunction()` and executed before `assert.throw` executes. So you end up running `assert.throw` with an object which is an instance of `SomeFunction`, rather than with a function that instantiates an object.